# auto reload browser when file content changed, saved in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been working on `node.js` project. my requirement is I want to load.txt file on browser. when I change and save this file, content should be updated. Browser should be auto refresh.

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    index.js
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/demo.txt');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected');
    });

    http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });

    var io = require('socket.io')(80);
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.watchFile('message.text', (curr, prev) => {
      console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime}`);
      console.log(`the previous mtime was: ${prev.mtime}`);
      // file changed push this info to client.
      io.emit('fileChanged', 'yea file has been changed.');
    });

    index.html
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    socket.on('fileChanged', function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    });
```

Comment: How are you saving the changes?

Comment: Do you want to edit a file in the browser and send it to the server when `x` happens?

Comment: .txt format, i loaded file by using above code, how to auto refresh the browser. what ever i change content in the .txt file it should shown on the browser after saving changes.

Comment: you can't "auto-refresh" the browser on the server-side

Comment: A server can't connect to a client and push data. You either have to set up a websocket connection from the browser that the server can use to send a message to the browser, telling your script running in the browser to refresh the page, or, set up a script in the browser that periodically asks the server if the file has been updated and refresh the page if so

Comment: yes iam using socket.io and express any link available?

Comment: you are already using socketIO?

Comment: i just installed searching how to use it for my requirement

Comment: you just made everything worse xD

Comment: iam testing in my commend

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can do this with two action:

**1. Watch file change on server-side. And push info to client**

You can watch file with node.js.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/cluster.json');
});

const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection',function (client) {
    console.log("Socket connection is ON!");
});

http.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watchFile('cluster.json', function(curr, prev){
    // file changed push this info to client.
    console.log("file Changed");
    io.emit('fileChanged', 'yea file has been changed.');
});
```

**2. Catch "file changed" info and refresh page on client side**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io("http://localhost:80");
    socket.on('fileChanged', function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting error io is not function. i posted code again is that correct?

Comment: you need to include the socket.io client in your html, as @hurricane wrote

Comment: you mean index.html?

Comment: if it's called index.html

Comment: @Ram socket.io consists of two parts server and client. First codes must be in server side(node.js) second codes must be in client side(index.html)

Comment: yeh little bit i know. new to nodejs in confusion

Comment: i created saparate js for it. should i place the first one in it.

Comment: confused in which folder which file i have to place this two codes?

Comment: @Ram I think you need to complete this example https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: i created saparate js file to load my .txt file it's loading. cant' i place this code in it. index.html means only one is in my folder.

Comment: now iam able to load my .txt file on browser localhost:3000 now i want to auto refresh when i save txt file. any help?

Comment: @Ram You need to write second code into your client codes. You can try it in index.html

Comment: Iam getting this output on cmd D:\QUP>node index.js
listening on *:3000
the current mtime is: Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
the previous mtime was: Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: @Ram You can add .io.on('connection') to first code.

Comment: @Ram I updated answer for you and it's working for me.

Comment: server restarting but not browser i want browser as well as server on my cmd /nodemon node.js correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using WebSockets. A very good package to work with WebSockets is [`Socket.io`](https://socket.io/), and you can use something like [`chokidar`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) or the native function [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to watch the file changes and then emit an messsage.

Or if you trying to do this only for development purposes, you should check [`webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack), [`gulp`](https://gulpjs.com/) or other task runner that have built-in functions to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Do polling for the file using Ajax. Your server could respond with `{changes: '{timestamp-of-file-modify}'}`. Now check if your last seen change time differs from response time.

If there is changes: `window.location.reload`

Comment: your saying ajax in nodejs